# Blocking Facebook Questions

Tags: facebook

Facebook has this new thing called [Facebook Questions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_features#Questions_2).

How do I block them? I cannot block them by clicking the 'X' sign and selecting *hide all* by this application, since they are by Facebook itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding these to [Adblock Plus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adblock_Plus) (ABP) at least helps hide the bulk of it.

```
###pagelet_adbox
##.adsCell
facebook.com##.fbQuestionsPollClickTarget
facebook.com##.pas.fbQuestionsPollResultsBar
facebook.com##.pollResultsBar
facebook.com##.fbQuestionsBlingBox
facebook.com##.pollOptions
facebook.com##.fbEigenpollRow
facebook.com##A[title="Ask specific people to answer"]
facebook.com##[href*="/home.php?sk=question"]
facebook.com##.fbEigenpollPager
facebook.com##.fbQuestionFollowLink
```

Comment: Doesnt work for me, perhaps I am configuring it incorrectly. I installed Ad Block Plus, copied the above code and pasted it into the "Add filter section"

Comment: Are you using Firefox or Chrome?  In Chrome you should be able to paste it in as raw (Adblock > Options > Add your own filters > Edit Filters as raw text).

Comment: I am not sure if there is an equivalent method in firefox, but copying in each of those lines one by one as rules (Adblock > Preferences > My Element Hiding Rules) should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily block Facebook Questions with the [F.B. Purity](http://www.fbpurity.com/) browser extension. It also lets you block and fix a number of other annoying "Facebook features", and it's available for Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Chrome Extension called [Hide FB Questions](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/fnfccinnkelhmobaenahkeidjiocmnld) which describes itself as:

> *Hiding all evidence of the "Questions" feature so your feed doesn't get cluttered with polls.*
>
> This is the *original* extension, but is NOT affiliated with Facebook in any way! The name has been changed due to copyright issues.

Comment: "Item not found. This item may have been removed by its author."

Comment: It works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove them from your feed. It also appears that if you answer a question, anyone with a facebook account can see your response and your name. Super sketchy.